# Is there a logical operator that returns true if only one of the conditions are true?

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

I'm trying to write a function that returns "ERROR" if one or two arguments are not a number, or less than 0.

```
if (Number.isNaN(num1) || Number.isNaN(num2) || num1 < 0 || num2 < 0)
{
    return "ERROR";
}
```

The logical OR would return true only if all of them are true, right? And the logical AND would do the same. Also, I cannot use the Not operator, as that would interfere with the rest of the else if in the function.

I'm sorry if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You mean “return `"ERROR"` if _exactly one_ of the conditions holds”? You could do something like that with `[Number.isNaN(num1), Number.isNaN(num2), num1 < 0, num2 < 0].filter(Boolean).length === 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical OR would return truthy if any of them are truthy. Logical AND would return truthy if all are truthy.  If you only want exactly one, theres no Logical XOR, but bit-wise XOR with `^`.

But I think in your case Logical OR is perfectly acceptable since you are validating input.

Comment: The thing is that when I execute these:
`
console.log (sumAll(10, "90"));
console.log (sumAll(10, [90, 1]));
`
they don't return ERROR, but they go to the next if. Are those input not considered NaN?

Comment: @ElíasFerreiraTabó please edit your question with a [mcve]

Comment: @ElíasFerreiraTabó you need to check the value for its type `Number.isNaN([10])` returns false - add `typeof num1 !== 'number'`